# C++ for each, hidden type cast

Tags: c++, foreach, type-conversion

I have a for each loop which iterates over a vector of pointers.  the pointers are to a base class.  In the for each loop I use the derived type as the type for the iterator. The render function is only defined in some of the derived classes, yet the code compiles and runs...  It crashes if the vector contains a pointer to a derived object which doesn't have the render function (obviously).

```
for each (DerivedClass* body in myVector)
{
    body->render();
}
```

This error came about in my code because when I wrote it the vector only contained pointers to the derived class but later on I decided to refactor the code and this changed.

Can anyone tell me the right way to trap this error?  Checking for a null pointer doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Are you sure that this is c++?

Comment: @SU3, It's an older MSVC syntax, deprecated ever since they supported standard range-based for loops.

Comment: Sounds like it just does a `static_cast` under the hood, so you can't check a posteriori. How about iterating with a `BaseClass *` and downcasting manually with `dynamic_cast` ?

Comment: another way around this is to implement `render()` in your base even though it won't do anything

Answer (score 3):

Really, the problem here is that Microsoft's foreach loop is too permissive. Microsoft has deprecated this extension in favour of the standard range-based for loop (since C++11):

```
for (DerivedClass* body : myVector) {
    body->render();   
}
```

Here, the head of the loop, won't compile because it cannot initialize a `DerivedClass*` from a `BaseClass*`.

Regarding actually getting this to compile, firstly, please rethink your design. You should be programming to interfaces, not to implementations. Having to rely on these objects being renderable when some aren't is a code smell. That said, it's possible through `dynamic_cast`:

```
for (auto base : myVector) {
    if (auto derived = dynamic_cast<DerivedClass*>(base)) {
        derived->render();
    }
}
```

Don't have C++11 (which I can only assume from the lack of the standard loop)? You can still use a traditional `for` loop with indices or iterators. You can also be more explicit about the types in my `dynamic_cast` example.

To add a little spin, sometimes it does come up where this type of casting is common (e.g., some compiler implementations). If this is determined to be a good design choice, you can wrap this code in an algorithm. For example, here's how it looks in C#:

```
foreach (var body in myVector.OfType<DerivedClass>()) {
    body.render();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, the problem is that only some of the pointers in your vector point to objects that are of a type that implements `render()`. If that's the case `dynamic_cast` will do the trick of checking for the right type.

```
for (DerivedClass *p : myVector) {
  class_implementing_render *q = dynamic_cast<class_implementing_render>(p);
  if (q) q->render();
}
```

Comment: Did you test this?